# vb.net insert record into dataset cell from a loop

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, vb.net-2010

```
 For j = 0 To wcData.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
  For i = 900 To 1700
    wcData.Tables("db").Rows(j)("range") = i
   Next
 Next
```

trying to insert "i" into each column cell of "range"

any suggestion.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim rowOffset As Integer = 900;

For j = 0 To wcData.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1 
    wcData.Tables("db").Rows(j).Item("range") =  rowOffset + j
Next
```

Comment: it inserts only 1700. This is what i'm trying to acheve
for example:
     if i = 900, j = 0; i = 901, j = 1; i = 902, j = 2..... etc.

thanks

T

Comment: No problem Gbolahan. Please mark the answer if it solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Dim rowOffset As Integer = 900

  For j = 0 To wcData.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
   wcData.Tables("ratingout").Rows(j).Item("range") = rowOffset + j
   If i >= 1700 Then
    Exit For
   End If
 Next
```

this worked for now.
thanks